# Geoserver timeout when trying to calculate native bounding boxes for large layers

Tags: java, oracle, geoserver

I'm working on a project involving connecting to an external oracle database as a data `store`. I am attempting to add several layers to `Geoserver` based on db Views in the oracle `store`.

**Many layers are fine:**
Several of the views are ingesting fine, apart from a fairly significant delay when clicking "Compute from data" to calculate the Native Bounding Box coordinates (minX, minY, maxX, maxY). The background task seems to complete after ~2-10minutes. This is fine...

**The problem:** 
There are some very large views which are not completing after clicking "Compute from data". The process appears to timeout. I’ve attached screenshots showing this issue. ie, the spinner dissapears but the bounding coordinates remain blank.

Has anyone come across this before? I’ve tried increasing the Jetty http.timeout and threads.timeout, no dice.

The progress spinner appears in the top right indicating the computation is occurring, it will spin for roughly 15minutes then simply disappears coordinate boxes remain blank. It merely stops with no error - I've checked the log file.

This server is running on a centos 7 box with plenty of ram. Geoserver itself is running with 3GB ram.

Have you ever experienced this?

Additionally, i was considering calculating these bounding box values manually against a CSV exported from the oracle View calculated against all geometry values. I could use a java package such as JTS, is there a better way?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JTS_Topology_Suite

Any help appreciated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is that Oracle spatial sucks when used in a general way, as GeoServer is designed to work with many databases it can't have (many) spatial speedup tricks in its database access code. A good database (e.g. PostGIS) is fast all the time, Oracle is only fast if you hand tune it using hints based on local knowledge. You don't say which version of GeoServer you are using but the latest version will probably be faster than an old one.

To calculate the bounds of the table you can ask Oracle for it using:

```
SELECT SDO_TUNE.EXTENT_OF('TABLE_NAME', 'SPATIAL_COLUMN');
```

or

```
select sdo_aggr_mbr(MY_GEOMETRY) from MY_TABLE;
```

This [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/104062/how-to-improve-performance-of-oracle-spatial-function-sdo-aggr-mbr) on the [GIS stackexchange site](https://gis.stackexchange.com/) discusses tuning these queries.

Comment: Thanks for the help, its geoserver 2.9.2

As for Oracle, unfortunately there's no choice, its a db running from a separate department. We have two different databases which are working as data stores. Oracle, and MySQL. I'm well aware that postgis is a good gis db but I have no say on the database engines atm.

Those queries are a big help and something I will look into.

Since asking the question what I have found interesting is that the problem of timeout only occurs on our centos box, when running locally on osx it takes a long time but finally completes, I can then use those coords

Comment: Also if you turn logging up to Developer level you can see the actual query that is being sent to Oracle and run it by hand.

Comment: thats a big help thank you @iant. I will do that. Also, what i have discovered just now when checking versions... is that locally i am running 2.9.2 on OSX and although the layer bounds compute task takes an extremely long time... ~ 1hour... it completes. Whereas the linux install on a centos AWS VM, is 2.10.0... its possible there is a bug/issue introduced. I will try 2.10.0 locally and see if the issue then occurs locally, then 2.10.1 and see if its fixed. I can also resort to 2.9.2 on the linux server if that version is indeed more solid for this case...

Comment: you mentioned about PostGIS. We actually do have more control over our mysql db which will be the source of a very large number of multipolygon geometry data. Although that db will need to remain in place for its existing web application purpose, Would you suggest working toward keeping it and a PostGIS db in sync as so far as the geo data views? Is the performance really worth an endeavour such as that?